# Router matches correct route only when opening in New Tab

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using fairly simple Router configuration:

```
const routes = (
<Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={Main}>
        <IndexRoute component={Home} />
        <Route path="login" component={Login} />
        <Route path="post/:postTitle" component={Post} />
        <Route path="dashboard" component={Dashboard} onEnter={requireAuth}>
          <Route path="posts" component={DashboardPostsContainer} />
          <Route path="edit" component={Editor} />
          <Route path="edit/*" component={Editor} />
        </Route>
        <Redirect from="*" to="/" />
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
);
```

The problem is, that when I'm in `/dashboard/posts` route and click `<Link>` redirecting to `/dashboard/edit/This is sample post` it routes me to `/` path.

However, when I Right Click that `Link` element and select `Open in new Tab` it works flawlessly.

`edit/` route without wildcard after slash also works as intended.

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you make sure the path is escaped? (encodeURIComponent)

Comment: I tried that. My link looks like this:
`<Link to={computeEditPostUrl(props.title)} className="no-link-recoration">`
where computedEditPostUrl is:

`const computeEditPostUrl = (title) => (\`edit/${encodeURIComponent(title)}\`);`

It doesn't help however.

Comment: Then, I don't understand how it's possible that you have a `Link` with `/dashboard/edit/This is sample post`. It should be `/dashboard/edit/This%20is%20sample%20post`

Comment: Rendered DOM looks like this:
`<a class="no-link-recoration" href="edit/This%20is%20a%20sample%20post"><span class="grey-text">Edit</span></a>`

As I said, when clicked normally - doesn't work. When opened in new tab - works as intended. 

Source: https://github.com/RafalWilinski/throttle/blob/master/app/routes.jsx

Comment: What happens if you remove your `Redirect`? Also, why are you using `edit/*` instead of `edit/:someParam`?

Comment: I tried `*` because I had no luck with `:someParam`, I thought it's "wider".

After removing fallback redirect, URL inside browser has changed to `/dashboard/edit/This%20is%20a%20sample%20title` (correct) however I get following error in the console:
`bundle.js:20792 Warning: [react-router] Location "edit/This%20is%20a%20sample%20title" did not match any routes`

Comment: Okay, what version of [tag:react-router] do you have?

Comment: Im using 2.0.1 version

Comment: Weird. Try updating to the last version and try again. Does the problem exist if you try something like `dashboard/edit/test`?

Comment: I've just updated router to 2.4.0. Issue still persists. I've also changed Link's `to={'edit/test'}` and it also doesn't work.

Comment: Changing `to` param from `edit/${title}` to `/dashboard/edit/${title}` resolved issue. I really don't know why relative URLs doesn't work while absolute does.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `to` param of `<Link/>` from relative (without `/` preceding path) to absolute solved problem.

In my case from `edit/${title}` to `/dashboard/edit/${title}`.